# Chrome opening every webpage inside iframe

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I don't know what is happening with my PC and my Google Chrome browser. It is opening every webpage inside a iframe. I dont know why. I have tried resetting all the chrome settings and I even have tried deleting all the data ( deleted all folders related to chrome ) and re installing chrome over 10 times and still the same problem. It is really giving me pain.

[image]

You can clearly see that I am on the startup page of chrome and its showing me **view frame source** and **reload frame**. I searched it on google found 0 solutions or even 0 topics about this kind of issues. So I am really begging for a solution here..

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour in Chrome and Chromium on Ubuntu.

Comment: This belongs on Superuser, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

There is no actual frame, it's just an UI issue. There is a Chrome bug report about it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1085040

Let's hope it will be resolved in an upcoming update.